# AWS ECS Fargate autoscaling (scale-in) not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, aws-auto-scaling

ECS service is configured to have desired count = 1 as part of initial setup.
Auto-scaling with policy type = "TargetTrackingScaling" and PredefinedMetricType = "ECSServiceAverageMemoryUtilization" is set with target value 75%,
i.e. it should auto scale if average memory used by service is above or below 75%.

Auto scale target is configured with Max capacity = 5, Min capacity = 1 (target = ECS service in this case)

After application started, Memory utilization increased above 75% as more and more requests hit the tasks which triggered cloudwatch scale-out alarm and a new task is successfully added to the service.

Once all the requests were processed, memory utilization came down to ~58% which triggered a scale-in cloudwatch alarm but a task was not removed from the ecs service.
The two running tasks have memory utilized ~3165MB and ~1454MB and max memory configured for tasks is 4096.
Can anyone tell why a task was not removed ?

Comment: Maybe you disabled scale-in?

Comment: Nope, i don't have DisableScaleIn=true in my config.

Comment: Open http connections on all tasks?

Comment: @RonanCunningham - nope, two nodes are idle for long time now and there is no active HTTP request.

Comment: Do you have the setup in a cf template you can share?